# Chart.js custom tooltips label

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have a line chart where my data are currently set but I need to make a custom label for the box shown when cursor is over the point.
I get sent an object to my chart with 3 keys that each one of them represent an array and actually this is the array:

```
{"labels":["March","April","May","June","July","August"],
"subscriptions":[{"3x java 6 mujor 123123 (seanca)":1,"3x java mujor 12 (seanca)":1,"1x java ditor 1 (seanca)":1},{"3x java 6 mujor 123123 (seanca)":1,"3x java mujor 12 (seanca)":7,"1x java ditor 1 (seanca)":2},{"3x java 6 mujor 123123 (seanca)":1,"3x java mujor 12 (seanca)":6,"1x java ditor 1 (seanca)":21},{"3x java 6 mujor 123123 (seanca)":1,"3x java mujor 12 (seanca)":1,"1x java ditor 1 (seanca)":3},{"3x java 6 mujor 123123 (seanca)":1,"3x java mujor 12 (seanca)":1},{"1x java ditor 1 (seanca)":4,"3x java mujor 12 (seanca)":2}],
"quantity":[3,10,28,5,2,6]}
```

I had sent data.quantity to data of dataset and data.labels to labels of dataset.
And for the data.subscriptions I have sent it to tooltips for the label appearing on hover.
The code is wright down below.
This labels appear but I want list them under each other , but "\n" does not work in this part.
Is there any thing I should add to make it possible?

```
function generateMonthFrequentationsLinearChart(data) {
    let monthLineChartData = {
        labels: data.labels,
        datasets: [{
            label: "# abonime",
            backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)'
            ],
            borderColor: [
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)'
            ],
            borderWidth: 1,
            data: data.quantity
        }],
        tooltipText: data.subscriptions,
    };

    let ctxL = $('#lineChart');
    monthFrequentationLineChart = new Chart(ctxL, {
        type: 'line',
        data: monthLineChartData,
        options: {
            responsive: true,
            legend: {
                display: true,
            },
            title: {
                display: true,
                text: 'Line Chart'
            },
            tooltips: {
                callbacks: {
                    label: function (tooltipItem, data) {
                        var array = data.tooltipText[tooltipItem.index];
                        var label = "";
                        for (var text in array){
                            label += text + ": " + array[text] + '\n |';
                        }
                        label = label.slice(0, -1);
                        return label;
                    },
                    title: function (context, tooltipItem) {
                        return  context[0].xLabel + "  Total: " + context[0].yLabel;
                    }
                },
                displayColors: false,
                hasIndicator: true,
                intersect: false
            },
            scales: {
                yAxes: [{
                    ticks: {
                        beginAtZero: true
                    }
                }]
            }
        }
    });
}
```

I have done this code for the tooltips and I get the data but they don't appear listed

```
tooltips: {
                callbacks: {
                    label: function (tooltipItem, data) {
                        var array = data.tooltipText[tooltipItem.index];
                        var label = "";
                        for (var text in array){
                            label += text + ": " + array[text] + '\n |';
                        }
                        label = label.slice(0, -1);
                        return label;
                    },
                    title: function (context, tooltipItem) {
                        return  context[0].xLabel + "  Total: " + context[0].yLabel;
                    }
                },
                displayColors: false,
                hasIndicator: true,
                intersect: false
            }
```

they appear like this :  3x java 6 mujor 123123 (seanca) :1 |3x java mujor 12 (seanca) :1 |1x java ditor 1 (seanca):1
As one line.

Comment: So what is the expected output?

Comment: The expected output is to have a label that have listed elements not a simple line text, where all element are in one line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do here is instead of building string for label you can build array and just simply return it.
So this is how your label callback will look like.

```
label: function (tooltipItem, data) {
  const labelArr = [];
  var array = data.tooltipText[tooltipItem.index];
  for (var text in array){
    labelArr.push(text + ": " + array[text])
  }
  return labelArr;
},
```